# Adding an element to the root element

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I have an XML file that looks something like this (a maven `pom.xml` if anyone's familiar):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    ...
</project>
```

I wanted to add add a `<packaging>` element so that it looks like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

So I did this:

```
doc = (Document)builder.build(modelToWriteTo);
rootProj = doc.getRootElement();
Element packagingTag = rootProj.getChild("packaging");
if(packagingTag != null) {
        packagingTag.setText(elementValue);         
} else {
    packagingTag = new Element("packaging").setText(elementValue);
    rootProj.addContent(packagingTag);  
}
```

so that if there's a child element called "packaging" then I just want to reset the value, if not then I want to add a new tag.

The problem is when I did that my `<packaging>` element came as:

```xml
<project>
    <packaging xmlns="">pom</packaging>
</project>
```

So I read somewhere it might be something to do with the namespace, so I changed my code to:

```
doc = (Document)builder.build(modelToWriteTo);
rootProj = doc.getRootElement();
Element packagingTag = rootProj.getChild("packaging");
if(packagingTag != null){
        packagingTag.setText(elementValue);         
} else {
    packagingTag = new Element("packaging").setText(elementValue);
    packagingTag.setNamespace(rootProj.getNamespace());
    rootProj.addContent(packagingTag);      
}
```

and it appears nicely without the `xmlns` attribute:

```xml
<project>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

**However,** when another thread comes in to read it again, and find `rootProj.getChild("packaging")`, it returns `null`.
thus, another attempt to modify the packaging tag lead to the thread thinking that it doesn't exist and adds a new tag resulting in:

```xml
<project>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

with the previous code where I didn't set the namespace, it was able to retrieve `rootProj.getChild("packaging")`.....

I must have miss something here but I can't see where. Please help!

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without knowing which XML API you are using.

Comment: jdom per tag but agree that it should be up front and center: Using JDOM ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`Element.getChild(String, Namespace)`](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#getChild%28java.lang.String,%20org.jdom.Namespace%29) version of the method and pass the correct namespace (which in this case is `http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0`).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for the `packaging` element that's in no namespace, but no such node exists, because your `packaging` node is in the default namespace (`xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"`). You need to specify this namespace when selecting the element:

```
Element packagingTag = rootProj.getChild("packaging", 
    Namespace.getNamespace("http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"));
```

**Note:** The reason it worked before is because this:

```
<packaging xmlns="">pom</packaging>
```

...contains a namespace "undeclaration" (`xmlns=""`) that reverts the element to existing in no namespace.

Comment: so it seems like everytime when I want to get a child, i have to state a namespace. troublesome, but it works. instead of going Namespace.getNamespace(..) , i just used rootProj.getChild("packaging", rootProj.getNamespace()) .. Thanks

Comment: @ALQH - Right, it's significant that an element is in a namespace or that it isn't. Fundamentally, you're not asking for the right node if you don't specify the namespace the node exists in.